# Ubuntu gets stuck at shutdown screen

Tags: shutdown

I have just installed `e4rat` (a program to make your boot time faster) and set it up. Now the boot time is much faster, but when I want to shutdown or reboot my machine gets stuck at the shutdown-screen.

What can I do to prevent this?

I'm not using Ubuntu on Virtualbox. Ubuntu (13.04) is my real hard-drive-installed PC-System. But I have installed Virtualbox from the Software Center on my Ubuntu 13.04.
Here are the last lines from `/var/log/kern.log`

```
 Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.741138] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.741215] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.752223] scsi 0:0:1:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SAMSUNG SP0802N  TK10 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.752340] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] 156368016 512-byte logical blocks: (80.0 GB/74.5 GiB)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.752351] sd 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.752417] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.752419] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.752453] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.788612]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.788899] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.824219] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3515.547 MHz
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.824222] Switching to clocksource tsc
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.860181] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.864176] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.868179] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.868207] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.880172] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0461, idProduct=0010
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.880175] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.880177] usb 4-1: Product: USB Keyboard
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.880178] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: NOVATEK
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.898203] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.898205] usbhid: USB HID core driver
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.900381] input: NOVATEK USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input2
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.900466] hid-generic 0003:0461:0010.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [NOVATEK USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:12.1-1/input0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.902202] input: NOVATEK USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/input/input3
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    2.902290] hid-generic 0003:0461:0010.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [NOVATEK USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:12.1-1/input1
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.067975] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068137] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068138] [drm] Connector 0:
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068139] [drm]   VGA-1
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068141] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e40 0x7e40 0x7e44 0x7e44 0x7e48 0x7e48 0x7e4c 0x7e4c
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068142] [drm]   Encoders:
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068143] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068144] [drm] Connector 1:
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068145] [drm]   DVI-D-1
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068145] [drm]   HPD1
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068147] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e50 0x7e50 0x7e54 0x7e54 0x7e58 0x7e58 0x7e5c 0x7e5c
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068147] [drm]   Encoders:
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068148] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_LVTMA
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.068166] [drm] radeon: power management initialized
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.100826] [drm] fb mappable at 0xD0142000
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.100827] [drm] vram apper at 0xD0000000
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.100829] [drm] size 8294400
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.100830] [drm] fb depth is 24
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.100831] [drm]    pitch is 7680
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.100886] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.116026] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.119861] radeon 0000:01:05.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.119862] radeon 0000:01:05.0: registered panic notifier
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.119867] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.29.0 20080528 for 0000:01:05.0 on minor 0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.247801] usb 10-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.267107] usb 10-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0ace, idProduct=1211
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.267110] usb 10-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.267112] usb 10-1: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.267114] usb 10-1: Manufacturer: ZyDAS
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.399652] usb 3-3: new low-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.544557] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Ut163    USB2FlashStorage 0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.544930] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.545550] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 3948543 512-byte logical blocks: (2.02 GB/1.88 GiB)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.546301] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.546304] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.547056] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.547058] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.550419] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.550420] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.566502] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=0210
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.566505] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.566508] usb 3-3: Product: PS/2+USB Mouse
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.573658] input: PS/2+USB Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/input/input4
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.573746] hid-generic 0003:04F3:0210.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PS/2+USB Mouse] on usb-0000:00:12.0-3/input0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.658439]  sdb: sdb1
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.661296] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.661299] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    3.661301] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    4.073427] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    4.073430] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    5.059843] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [    5.068086] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.713967] Adding 3665916k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:3665916k 
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.719413] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.864320] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.865214] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000b00-0x0000000000000b07 SystemIO conflicts with Region \SOR1 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.865225] MCE: In-kernel MCE decoding enabled.
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.865228] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.866522] sp5100_tco: SP5100/SB800 TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v0.05
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.866587] sp5100_tco: PCI Revision ID: 0x3c
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.866605] sp5100_tco: failed to find MMIO address, giving up.
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.868247] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.868991] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.871409] AMD64 EDAC driver v3.4.0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.871444] EDAC amd64: DRAM ECC disabled.
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.871454] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.871454]  Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.871454]  (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.874034] it87: Found IT8728F chip at 0x228, revision 1
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.874051] it87: Beeping is supported
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.883133] parport_pc 00:09: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.883186] parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.914736] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.923273] microcode: CPU0: patch_level=0x0600081c
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.955801] input: HDA ATI SB Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input5
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.959980] input: HDA ATI SB Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input6
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.960047] input: HDA ATI SB Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input7
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.960107] input: HDA ATI SB Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input8
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.960168] input: HDA ATI SB Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input9
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.960467] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:05.1: setting latency timer to 64
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.970611] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:05.1/sound/card1/input10
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.971885] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.978601] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.984004] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.984007] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.984009] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.984012] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.984013] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.984015] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   40.984017] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.039772] usb 10-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.057111] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880103c5e400
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.057114] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880103c5e440
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.057116] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880103c5e480
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.057117] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880103c5e4c0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.060238] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.060384] zd1211rw 10-1:1.0: phy0
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.060404] usbcore: registered new interface driver zd1211rw
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.118265] microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x0600081c
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.118273] microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x0600081c
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.118280] microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x0600081c
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.118288] microcode: CPU4: patch_level=0x0600081c
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.118295] microcode: CPU5: patch_level=0x0600081c
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.118345] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.129513] kvm: Nested Virtualization enabled
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.129518] kvm: Nested Paging enabled
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.361009] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=820 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.361168] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=765 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.361174] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=764 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.361269] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=820 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.361412] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=820 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.361573] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=765 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.361578] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=764 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.361796] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=765 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.361801] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=764 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   41.363174] type=1400 audit(1373032214.404:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/ntpd" pid=850 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.180878] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.373804] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.373821] NET: Registered protocol family 31
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.373828] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.374105] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.374109] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.374117] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.377019] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.377022] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.377029] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.383213] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.383222] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.383224] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.648253] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.648275] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.648299] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    Jul  5 15:50:15 my-pc-name kernel: [   42.648615] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.022195] zd1211rw 10-1:1.0: firmware version 4605
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.027245] zd1211rw 10-1:1.0: zd1211 chip 0ace:1211 v4330 high 00-30-95 RF2959_RF pa0 -----
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.027577] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.030374] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.030376] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.030378] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.030379] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.030381] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.030382] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm)
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.045335] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.045556] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    Jul  5 15:50:16 my-pc-name kernel: [   43.567501] Unsafe core_pattern used with suid_dumpable=2. Pipe handler or fully qualified core dump path required.
    Jul  5 15:50:17 my-pc-name kernel: [   44.086456] vboxdrv: Found 6 processor cores.
    Jul  5 15:50:17 my-pc-name kernel: [   44.086626] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0x394 offMax=0x2efb
    Jul  5 15:50:17 my-pc-name kernel: [   44.086695] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
    Jul  5 15:50:17 my-pc-name kernel: [   44.086696] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.2.10_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a0004).
    Jul  5 15:50:17 my-pc-name kernel: [   44.108998] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
    Jul  5 15:50:17 my-pc-name kernel: [   44.305046] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
    Jul  5 15:50:17 my-pc-name kernel: [   44.305053] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
    Jul  5 15:50:20 my-pc-name kernel: [   47.376693] audit_printk_skb: 86 callbacks suppressed
    Jul  5 15:50:20 my-pc-name kernel: [   47.376697] type=1400 audit(1373032220.423:40): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1235 profile="/sbin/dhclient" name="/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient6-eth0.conf" pid=2094 comm="dhclient" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

Comment: Do you see anything suspicious like an error line? If you see the logo just press the arrow down button on the keyboard to see these lines. Does your hard drive is in use while shutting down? Check the hard disk led if it is flashing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!When I press ESC or the arrow down key, there are some lines, but no real errors. The last line that appears is "*Stopping Vitrualbox kernel modules". While the boot screen is stucking, I think the hard drive is not in usage, because the led is off and it just shortly lights a half second maybe every 2 minutes. Shall I post the output of /var/log/kern.log or is it useless?

Comment: If you could, it may help to solve your problem. By the way are you using it on a virtual machine or are you using linux mint ?

Comment: OK, I posted /var/log/kern.log in my first post, because I'm not able to this this in a new post. I hope this is OK!

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall virtualbox then shutting down? Maybe the unloading of its modules prevent the system from shutting down. By the way your kern.log file only covers your startup, from grub to desktop.

Comment: In some cases either `modemmanager`(which allows different modems or usb broadbands to be used) or `network-manager`(which provide a UI to easily connect to the network or internet) could also prevent shutdown

You can also try to uninstall them but beware that the internet connection could be lost, especially when using wifi

Comment: OK I uninstalled Virtualbox with its Kernel Modules but Ubuntu still doesn't shutdown. That last message on the screen is now: Speech dispatcher disabled and there is no "OK" behind. ...And my machine is extreemly slow. When I try to click on soemthing it takes 5 seconds and my CPU usage is extremely high. What's going on here? So I installed Virtualbox again and there was one error: "No suitable module for running kernel found...[fail]",but anyway the installation procceeded. What shall I do now?

Comment: bug with `e4rat`? OP says they fixed by upgrading kernel, but can't condone their answer due to potentially dangerous commands. Considering this no-repro.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it:

First of all the upper bugs were not the only one. I also had an extremely high memory usage, the graphics didn't work right, everything ran extreeemly slow, my CPU usage was always about 90% (I have an AMD-FX6300 Six Core!!!), I couldn't mount devices and the sound did not work. So here is what I did to solve this. I just installed the new 3.9 Kernel manually like that:

```
wget http://goo.gl/g1XHX
chmod +x g1XHX
sudo sh g1XHX
```

**g1XHX:**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$(tput setaf 3)--- Kernel 3.9.4 - lffl will be installed in an `uname -i` system---$(tput sgr0)"
echo ""
sleep 2
read -p "Press Enter to continue, or abort by pressing CTRL+C" nothing
echo ""
echo ""

#i386 links
link1="http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_all.deb"
link2="http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_i386.deb"
link3="http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-image-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_i386.deb"

#amd64 links
url1="http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_amd64.deb"
url2="http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-image-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_amd64.deb"

#System architecture
arch=`uname -m`

if  [ $arch = i686 ] || [ $arch = i386 ]; then
    mkdir -p $HOME/kernel-i386 
    cd $HOME/kernel-i386
    wget -c $link1
    wget -c $link2
    wget -c $link3
    sudo dpkg -i *.deb  
    sudo rm -rf $HOME/kernel-i386
elif [ $arch = "x86_64" ]; then
    mkdir -p $HOME/kernel-amd64
    cd $HOME/kernel-amd64
    wget -c $link1
    wget -c $url1
    wget -c $url2
    sudo dpkg -i *.deb  
    sudo rm -rf $HOME/kernel-amd64
else
    echo "Unsupported Architecture"
fi
```

Then I rebooted and everything worked fine!

Comment: What? `wget`'ing a shortened/anonymous URL and blindly executing it? This demands some clarification.

Comment: Yes...I knew that this can be dangerous and silly, but I simply trusted itworld.com ;)

Comment: and it links to dropbox... is the the article - http://www.itworld.com/software/358507/install-linux-kernel-394-ubuntu-1304 doesn't look like your instructions will work compared to the article...